# Multinode Treepicker in Umbraco containing value in id

Tags: c#, umbraco7

I have Deal Document Type that contains Multinode Treepicker named device. This contains multiple record of the document type Device. Now every device has its Id defined by Umbraco. I have one integer value did and the list of deals named dealSelection.

I need to select all the Deals from dealSelection that conmtain the value did in Deal.device. Here is the code:

```
var did = 1010;
dealSelection = dealSelection.Where(x => ((((Deal)x).Device != null) && (/*PLEASE HELP WHAT TO PUT HERE*/));
```

Please help how to do the Linq so that I have in dealSelection all the deals having the device with id=did. I'm using Umbraco 7

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations

Comment: Guys please note this is more Umbraco question then simple Linq

Comment: on the contrary, this is in fact a simple `Linq` question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my question so that others that have same problem as me can get the answer:

```
var did = 1010;
dealSelection = dealSelection.Where(x => ((((Deal)x).Device != null) && (((Deal)x).Device.Any(d => d.Id == did)));
```